# How do we know how big to set the Heap?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, intermediate-language, intermediate-code

I'm trying to convert Java to an intermediate language and am in the process of figuring out how the intermediate language works.

I have the original Java code: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/cs132/mj/Factorial.java

And I have the Intermediate Code representation (VAPOR): http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-examples/Factorial.vapor

Here's another set: in Java: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/cs132/mj/BubbleSort.java

In VAPOR: http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-examples/BubbleSort.vapor

My question is, all of the VAPOR code has `t.0 = HeapAllocZ(x)` (where `x` is an `int`).  I'm wondering how the converter determines the heap size needs to be size `x`.  In `Factorial.vapor`, it's set to `4`.  In `BubbleSort.vapor`, it's set to `12`.

Thanks!

Comment: Most people just make a quick, reasonable guess and if the JVM runs out of heap, add more. Then if it keeps running out of a large heap, look for memory leaks etc

Comment: Based on what though?  I'm trying to automate the process, and I need some concrete basis for the guess

Comment: @Bohemian -- He appears to be asking about the size of individual objects, not the total amount of heap needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `HeapAlloc` is based on the size of the structure you are creating (assuming `4` and `12` are byte values).  I would think that looking at the variables your data structure uses, and counting the number of bytes those variables sum to would give you the number being allocated.

Comment: Yep, this is essentially what Java does, only the information is embedded in the reference to the Class object that is used in the `new` operation.  The object size stored in the Class object is calculated (by essentially totaling up the field sizes) when the class is "loaded".

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the Java version of Factorial has no data members.  The Java version of BubbleSort has two 4-byte ints (8 bytes total).

Presumably the "overhead" of an object is 4 bytes (the size of a pointer to the class object).

So Factorial has an object size of 4 and BubbleSort has an object size of 12.